# SynGrasp MATLAB toolbox

Tags: simulation, gesture, matlab, simulink

I've been looking for a MATLAB grasp/hand model that can be used for simulation of hand gestures. I found this SynGrasp, but can't seem to find the parameters for the joints' angles in any of the examples. Where can I find them? If not that, does anyone know a Simulink or Matlab hand gesture simulator?

Comment: This is a so specific question that I wonder if you will get many responses. I would contact the authors for this information. Since they already published their code I think they will be quite open about sharing their parameter.

Comment: You're probably right, but I was hoping an alternative toolbox/model. Will try to contact them. Thanks

Comment: You might want to look at SimMechanics (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/simmechanics/), but you'll have to create the model yourself from building blocks.